# Python - Shoot a bullet in the direction (angle in degrees) my spaceship is facing

Tags: python, pygame

There are a lot of questions about this. But none of them have answers that solve my problem in specific, I've tried to google this all day.

My problem is simple.

I have this space ship that I can move and rotate around and I'm already tracking it's heading, the direction it's facing. For example in the image below the ship is heading approximately **45 degrees** It goes from 0° (starting top and going clockwise) to 359°

[image]

I just need to make a bullet go straight forward the direction (heading) my spaceship is facing, starting from the X,Y coordinate my spaceship currently is

The Projectile class:

```
class Projectile(object) :

    def __init__(self, x, y, vel, screen) :
        self.screen = screen
        self.speed = 1 #Slow at the moment while we test it
        self.pos = Vector2D(x, y)
        self.velocity = vel #vel constructor parameter is a Vector2D obj
        self.color = colors.green

    def update(self) :
        self.pos.add(self.velocity)

    def draw(self) :
        pygame.draw.circle(self.screen, self.color, self.pos.int().tuple(), 2, 0)
```

Now the shoot method of my ship class:

```
class Ship(Polygon) :

    # ... A lot of ommited logic and constructor

    def shoot(self) :
        p_velocity = # .......... what we need to find
        p = Projectile(self.pos.x, self.pos.y, p_velocity, self.screen)
        # What next?
```

Comment: Where is the logic for updating `self.pos` ? Maybe keep a list of the last 2 position and calculate velocity from them?

Comment: @jmunsch I don't think I understood properly. Both classes have a <pos> property which is simply their position on the screen. They're updated by adding velocity values to it each frame

Comment: What library do you import for Vector2D?

Comment: Vector 2D is a custom class I wrote myself. It just makes operations with X,Y stuff. Like add, multiply, get vectors from angles (which I use to make the spaceship move forward the direction is facing) etc. The principle that is used for the ship doesn't seem to work on the bullet, that's confusing. Check it out here https://gist.github.com/anonymous/fb226b641649905cf059fbbb4c0f123d

Comment: @JuanBonnett If i'm not mistaken, [Pygame already provides a two dimensional vector class](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2).

Comment: Oh yeah! My class just do a couple things this pygame class doesn't by default. Let's call it a helper class, it's not mean to be complete and complex :P

Comment: oh what about something like this for the ship `p_velocity=self.velocity` and then for the projectile `self.speed=vel + 1`? that way the projectile has the same velocity.x and velocity.y as the ship, plus some extra so the projectile isn't moving at the same speed.

Comment: @jmunsch It wouldn't work since in this minigame the spaceship can drift so the bullet wouldn't behave like a bullet but like something you just drop out the window

Comment: Ah yeah, I know what you mean with the spaceship drift. Whats wrong with `Vector2D().create_from_angle(ship_angle, 3, return_instance=True)` the `create_from_angle` looks like it might be close?

Comment: Yeah, as I mentioned in a comment above, it is weird that the same principle that it's used with the ship to move forward the direction is facing (it accelerates, the speed is not constant) doesn't apply to the projectile

Comment: @JuanBonnett do you have the source code online?

Comment: I can create a public repo if you want

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130868/discussion-between-jmunsch-and-juan-bonnett).

Answer (score 1):

Given the ships angle, try:

```
class Projectile(object) :
    def __init__(self, x, y, ship_angle, screen) :
        self.screen = screen
        self.speed = 5 #Slow at the moment while we test it
        self.pos = Vector2D(x,y)
        self.velocity = Vector2D().create_from_angle(ship_angle, self.speed, return_instance=True)
        self.color = colors.green

    def update(self) :
        self.pos.add(self.velocity)

    def draw(self) :
        pygame.draw.circle(self.screen, self.color, self.pos.int().tuple(), 2, 0)
```

[image]

The relevant part of `Vector2D`:

```
def __init__(self, x = 0, y = 0) : # update to 0
    self.x = x
    self.y = y

def create_from_angle(self, angle, magnitude, return_instance = False) :
    angle = math.radians(angle) - math.pi / 2
    x = math.cos(angle) * magnitude
    y = math.sin(angle) * magnitude
    print(x, y, self.x, self.y, angle)
    self.x += float(x)
    self.y += float(y)
    if return_instance :
        return self
```

Comment: Gonna try to show you how it behaves when we do this

Comment: What's happening here is that the bullets are being created in the 0,0 coordinate, not where the ship is :s

Comment: How in the world do you create a position from an angle?

Comment: Also why points with *eiher* x ir y coordinates of zero get special treatment?

Comment: @n.m. angle + magnitude, and the projectiles were being drawn at 0,0 because the projectiles weren't being redrawn with the updated x,y source might still be available here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130868/discussion-between-jmunsch-and-juan-bonnett

Comment: You are either adding velocity to position, or replacing position with velocity. What about (0,100)? Why do you need this check anyway? Can you explain it to me like I'm a rubber duck?

Comment: @n.m. yes that makes more sense. `create_from_angle` might have a better name. and that check wasn't necessary.

Comment: Should we update the question so it points to the new problem? That there's an offset when bullets are being shot from certain angles.

Comment: @JuanBonnett should probably be a seperate question, with a link to this page for reference.