# Python - Make my spaceship shoot in the direction its facing Part 2

Tags: python, vector, pygame

**EDITED, SOLUTION AT THE BOTTOM OF THE QUESTION**

I had some improvements with the help of some nice people in this question: [Python - Shoot a bullet in the direction (angle in degrees) my spaceship is facing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41205388/5228999).

The problem now is that although the principle that makes the spaceship accelerate in the direction is facing, doesn't seem to work with the projectiles. There seems to be a weird offset when the bullets are shot from the ship in certain angles.

[image]

I'm gonna put the code below, the methods UPDATE() and BOOST() are the ones in charge of making the ship moving and it works.

Projectiles use almost the same principle, without acceleration.

**Here is a video so you can visualize the game running and see what's wrong https://youtu.be/-s7LGuLhePI**

This is my Ship and vector class which are the ones that had to do with the problem. **(I'm gonna omit and remove the methods that are not necessary to be shown here)**

Class Ship contains the ship element and also the Projectile class

```
import pygame
import colors
import math
from vectors import Vector2D
from polygon import Polygon
from helpers import *

class Ship(Polygon) :

    def __init__(self, x, y, screen) :
        self.screen = screen
        self.pos = Vector2D(x, y)
        self.size = 18
        self.color = colors.green
        self.rotation = 0
        self.points = [
                        (-self.size, self.size),
                        (0, self.size / 3),
                        (self.size, self.size),
                        (0, -self.size)
                      ]
        self.translate((self.pos.x, self.pos.y))
        self.velocity = Vector2D(0, 0)
        self.projectiles = []

    def shoot(self) :
        p = Projectile(self.pos.x, self.pos.y, self.rotation, self.screen)
        self.projectiles.append(p)

    def turn(self, dir) :
        turn_rate = 4
        if dir == 'left' :
            deg = -turn_rate
        elif dir == 'right' :
            deg = turn_rate
        else :
            deg = 0

        self.rotate((self.pos.x, self.pos.y), deg)

        if self.rotation > 360 :
            self.rotation -= 360
        elif self.rotation < 0 :
            self.rotation += 360
        else :
            self.rotation += deg

        #print('HDG: ' + str(self.rotation))

    def boost(self) :
        #print(self.velocity.x, ',', self.velocity.y)
        force = Vector2D().create_from_angle(self.rotation, 0.1, True)

        #Limits the speed
        if (((self.velocity.x <= 4) and (self.velocity.x >= -4)) 
            or 
            ((self.velocity.y <= 4) and (self.velocity.y >= -4))) :
            self.velocity.add(force)

        #print('Velocity: ' + str(self.velocity.x) + ',' + str(self.velocity.y))

    def update(self) :
        #Adds friction
        f = 0.98
        self.velocity.mult((f, f))

        # Resets ship possition when it's out of the screen
        if self.pos.x > (self.screen.get_width() + self.size) :
            #print('COLLIDED RIGHT')
            self.pos.x -= self.screen.get_width() + self.size
            self.translate((-(self.screen.get_width() + self.size), 0))
        elif self.pos.x < -self.size :
            #print('COLLIDED LEFT')
            self.pos.x += self.screen.get_width() + self.size
            self.translate(((self.screen.get_width() + self.size), 0))
        if self.pos.y > (self.screen.get_height() + self.size) :
            #print('COLLIDED BOTTOM')
            self.pos.y -= self.screen.get_height() + self.size
            self.translate((0, -(self.screen.get_height() + self.size)))
        elif self.pos.y < -self.size :
            #print('COLLIDED TOP')
            self.pos.y += self.screen.get_height() + self.size
            self.translate((0, (self.screen.get_height() + self.size)))

        self.pos.x += self.velocity.x #TODO: simplify using V2D add function
        self.pos.y += self.velocity.y

        self.translate(self.velocity.tuple())

        #Update projectiles that have been shot
        for p in self.projectiles :
            p.update()

    def draw(self) :
        stroke = 3
        pygame.draw.polygon(self.screen, self.color, self.points, stroke)

        #Draws projectiles that have been shot
        for p in self.projectiles :
            p.draw()

class Projectile(object) :

    def __init__(self, x, y, ship_angle, screen) :
        self.screen = screen
        self.speed = 3 #Slow at the moment while we test it
        self.direction = ship_angle;
        self.pos = Vector2D(x, y)
        self.color = colors.green

    def update(self) :
        self.pos.add(Vector2D().create_from_angle(self.direction, self.speed, return_instance = True))

    def draw(self) :
        pygame.draw.circle(self.screen, self.color, self.pos.int().tuple(), 2, 0)
```

CLASS VECTOR (Used to calculate vectors based on elements "heading" and to apply velocities)

```
import math

class Vector2D() :

    def __init__(self, x = None, y = None) :
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def create_from_angle(self, angle, magnitude, return_instance = False) :
        angle = math.radians(angle) - math.pi / 2
        x = math.cos(angle) * magnitude
        y = math.sin(angle) * magnitude
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

        if return_instance :
            return self

    def tuple(self) :
        return (self.x, self.y)

    def int(self) :
        self.x = int(self.x)
        self.y = int(self.y)
        return self

    def add(self, vector) :
        if isinstance(vector, self.__class__) : # vector is an instance of this class
            self.x += vector.x 
            self.y += vector.y
        else : # vector is a tuple
            self.x += vector[0]
            self.y += vector[1]

    def mult(self, vector) :
        if isinstance(vector, self.__class__) : # vector is an instance of this class
            self.x *= vector.x 
            self.y *= vector.y
        else : # vector is a tuple
            self.x *= vector[0]
            self.y *= vector[1]
```

**SOLUTION BASED ON MARKED ANSWER**

Pygame.draw.circle() only accepts INTEGER values tuple as the position parameter, due to the calculations we were making, it was impossible because the results from the angle calculations were always float numbers.

The solution was to change the drawing method to use Ellipse instead of Circle in the Projectile Class:

```
class Projectile(object) :

    def __init__(self, x, y, ship_angle, screen) :
        self.screen = screen
        self.speed = 3 #Slow at the moment while we test it
        self.direction = ship_angle;
        self.velocity = Vector2D().create_from_angle(self.direction, self.speed, return_instance = True)
        self.pos = Vector2D(x, y)
        self.color = colors.green
        # Properties neccesary to draw the ellipse in the projectile position
        self.size = 4
        self.box = (0,0,0,0)

    def update(self) :
        self.pos.add(self.velocity)
        self.box = (self.pos.x, self.pos.y, self.size, self.size)

    def draw(self) :
        stroke = 2
        pygame.draw.ellipse(self.screen, self.color, self.box, stroke)
```

Comment: BTW: pygame has own [pygame.math.Vector2](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html)

Comment: I know, this class isn't mean to replace that class. See it as a Helper class with the methods I need for my specific game. Thanks!

Comment: use `print()` to see values in variables like `self.direction` or `Vector2D().create_from_angle()` and this way you can find what is the problem. BTW in `Projectile.update()` you calculate `Vector2D().create_from_angle()` all the time but you could do it only once in `__init__`.

Comment: Tried it, doesn't make any differece. I'm gonna leave it at the constuctor since it seems more efficient. thank you. and the output actually are very long float numbers that dont say much :s

Comment: @JuanBonnett It is tough to test this without being able to run it. Would it be possible to provide the source code? My main question would be like furas about `Vector2D().create_from_angle()`. Why is there a `- math.pi / 2` in that function? From what I see here, the error could be there or in the `Ship().turn()` function. There is a call to a `rotate()` function in there, but I find no other mentions of it in the source code posted here. Also, I think you should add the `deg` to rotation first before checking if it is between 0 and 360 (a modulo function could get rid of if statements).

Comment: @user2588654 gonna try that. You can download the .py files here: http://expirebox.com/download/6144c6887f1eb7f4308f17bcb9aa4f24.html

It uses Python 3.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that the error is surprisingly in your `Vector2D` class, but not in the function you would expect! Your `Vector2D().create_from_angle()` function is fine and creates the correct angle assuming up is 0 and angle value increases clockwise, even if it is against the "standard math convention" of 0 being to the right and counter-clockwise being increasing angle value.

The **real issue** is in your `Vector2D().int()` function, which is being used as part of your `draw()` function in the `Projectile` class. Casting `float` numbers to `int` simply truncates off the decimal values,  so you can use the `int` cast along with python's `round` function as follows:

```
def int(self) :
    self.x = int(round(self.x))
    self.y = int(round(self.y))
    return self
```

However, even if you do this fix, you will notice that the angle is still slightly off due to rounding compared to the tip of your ship. This is due to the fact that `self.pos.int()` under your `Projectile.draw()` function **overwrites** the current position with an inaccurate, rounded-off version that keeps on being added to in the `Projectile.update()` function. The best solution may be to avoid your `Vector2D.int()` function and replace your `Projectile.draw()` function with this:

```
def draw(self) :
    pos_x = int(round(self.pos.x))
    pos_y = int(round(self.pos.y))
    pygame.draw.circle(self.screen, self.color, (pos_x, pos_y), 2, 0)
```

The above modification will make your projectiles shoot perfectly from the tip of your ship, but will result in jittering as the position sometimes rounds up and sometimes rounds down in the x or y coordinate. Using a modified `Vector2D.int()` function resulted in non-jittery, but inaccurate, projectile shooting. Which error is best is up to you. Let me know if this is clear!

Comment: It makes a lot of sense. The draw.circle(..) function from Pygame throws an error (unlike draw.polygon) when I put values that aren't int(), maybe that's the root of the problem, I think I shall change the shape. Let's see.

Comment: Check my edited question, problem solved, just added something to your solution :)! Thank you so much, made the day!

Comment: @JuanBonnett Nice call with the ellipse! Now you don't have to worry about ugly rounding!